# Inheritance: Constructor in base class and derived class

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

Why is there a need of a constructor that excepts no arguments in the base class, if a constructor has to be put in the derived class?

```
public class profile 
{
    int experience;
    string qualification;
    string skills;

    public profile(int exp, string qual, string skill)
    {
        experience = exp;
        qualification = qual;
        skills = skill;
    }

    public void DisplayProfile() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(experience);
        Console.WriteLine(qualification);
        Console.WriteLine(skills);
    }
}

public class resume:profile
{
    string Firstname;
    string Lastname;
    string description;
    string volunteer;
    string achievements;

    public resume(string fname, string lanme, string des, string vol, string ach)
    {
        Firstname = fname;
        Lastname = lanme;
        description = des;
        volunteer = vol;
        achievements = ach;
    }

    public void DisplayResume() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Firstname);
        Console.WriteLine(Lastname);
        Console.WriteLine(description);
        Console.WriteLine(volunteer);
        Console.WriteLine(achievements);
    }
}
```

This is my code now i am getting an error at the resume constructor that profile does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

This error is removed if i overload the constructor in the base class by making an extra constructor that excepts 0 arguments.

Now i cannot understand the reason for this.

Comment: Until unless you are not calling "super class" constructor with parameters there is no need of creating constructor in "super class"

Comment: he compiler does not complain because he **needs** a parameterless base-constructor but because he did not add the `this(...)` to in the derived classes constructor it was assumed to have one

Comment: @Siddharth ok this makes more sense now and you have your answer - but why do you use *lower*-case for your class-names?

Comment: Well iv just started coding in C# and have not coded in any other language   as such. Though im aware of the pascal and camel casing, im yet develop it as a habit of using these in the naming process during coding. @Carsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of inheritence.

Here is a example

```
class BaseClass
{
  public BaseClass(){Console.WriteLine("This is Base Class")} // This is Base Class constructor (parameterless)
}

class DerivedClass:BaseClass{

 public DerivedClass(){Console.WriteLine("This is Derived Class")} // This is Derived Class constructor (parameterless)

}
```

Now in your console Main program create object of DerivedClass

```
  DerivedClass c=new DerivedClass();
```

At this line you will get two console output

```
  This is Base Class
  This is Derived Class
```

This is because constructors are called from base to derived.In your case when you call `resume` constructor it looks for default constructor of `profile`.It does find constructor of profile but the constructor here has 3 parameters so it expects you to  provide 3 parameters which you can do using

```
  public resume(string fname, string lanme, string des, string vol, string ach)
         :this(10,"","")
  {
  }
```

or by providing a default constructor with no parameters.

```
 public profile()
 {
 }
```

Comment: i tried using the first option but it says exp, qual and skill do not exist in the current context. though it works by the second option

Comment: its for passing the data to the profile here I have passed 10 for exp," " for qual and  " " for skill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question right. But given the code below, there is no need, and there is no compile-time error:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   //No constructor is OK
}

public class DeriveClass : BaseClass
{
   //No constructor is OK
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeriveClass dc = new DeriveClass(); 
    }
}
```

What it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i have posted the improved question let me know if you can help me with it now

Answer (score 0):

OP is correct and compiler complains about it. If you have to have a constructor with parameter then you will have to create a constructor with parameter in all children classes. Also you will have to call parent's constructor explicitly.

Constructor of your `resume` should be:

```
public resume(string fname, string lanme, string des, string vol, string ach,int exp, string qual, string skill) : base(exp, qual, skill)
{
    Firstname = fname;
    Lastname = lanme;
    description = des;
    volunteer = vol;
    achievements = ach;
}
```

See the modified parameter list and the way to call base().